# Android Media Recorder - Record Audio in Pieces

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I have an app that encodes in amr_nb format and output the file in amr. I want the recorded file to be broken into a series of amr files of 2 KB each. Got no clue on how to achieve this.

Here is the function called upon clicking Record Button

```
private void startRecording() {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());

    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the method called upon clicking Stop Button,

```
private void stopRecording() {
    if (null != recorder) {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();

        recorder = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setMaxFileSize(long)

Then register your listener to MediaRecorder that gets a callback when the max file size is reached, then set up MediaRecorder to record the next file. Be aware there's a (good?) chance this will not produce a series of gapless files.